# Simulation of QW gain

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, experimental-physics, semiconductor-physics, laser

For a student project, I need to compute and plot the gain of a semiconductor quantum-well.

In my case, I am interested to reproduce the results from Schwartz et al. (*[Investigation and comparison of optical gain spectra of (Al,In)GaN laser diodes emitting in the 375 nm to 470 nm spectral range](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/conference-proceedings-of-spie/6485/648506/Investigation-and-comparison-of-optical-gain-spectra-of-AlInGaN-laser/10.1117/12.705867.short?SSO=1)*). Unfortunately, everytime I try to compute using given formulas, I obtain false result...

So, I am here today to ask if someone can help me to find if there is errors in this article or if someone had already make such a simulation. And in this last case, if a script is available !

Thanks in advance,
Dj1312.

Comment: Is your script on GitHub?

Comment: I put it just here : https://github.com/Dj1312/qw_gain_simulation ! Thanks for your help :)